# How to configure SILEX .htaccess file for custom directory structure

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, silex

I have an application based on silex (php framework) it has different structure as compared to official structure i.e.

> www 
>   - silex 
>   - - my_name (replaced name for *web* folder) 
>   - - - public (all content, including *css/js/index.php*) 
>   - - - controllers 
>   - - - models 
>   - - - views 
>   - - vendor

I want to install it on a apache based server, that directs to public folder, instead of url like this `domain.name/silex/my_name/public`

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the documentroot you could try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.name$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain-name.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !silex/my_name/public/
RewriteRule (.*) /silex/my_name/public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: thank you very much that worked, but it would be great if you elaborate the answer..!!